# PRO-MK5 Spirit of gamer keyboard backlight does not work on ubuntu

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-backlight

I bought the [PRO-MK5 Spirit of gamer keyboard](https://spiritofgamer.com/gb/ready-to-play-packs/184-pro-mk5-3-in-1-pack-3700104445741.html) and I had the bad surprise to see that the LEDs on the keyboard work under Windows but not under Ubuntu 23.04.

I have already searched for solutions on the internet but none of them worked.

Thanks in advance.